# Replace a CALayer with a CAGradientLayer doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, quartz-core

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I want to change a background layer dynamically:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface MyClass : UIView
{
@private
    CALayer* _gradientBackground;
}
```

And some methods:

```
- (CALayer*)createLayerWithColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    CALayer* layer  = [CALayer layer];
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(NSLayerX, NSLayerY,
                                     NSLayerWidth, NSLayerHeight);
    layer.backgroundColor = [color CGColor];
    layer.cornerRadius = NSCornerRadius;

    return layer;
}
- (CAGradientLayer*)createLayerWithGradient:(UIColor*)startColor
                                   endColor:(UIColor*)endColor
{
    CAGradientLayer* gradientLayer  = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(NSLayerX, NSLayerY,
                                     NSLayerWidth, NSLayerHeight);
    gradientLayer.colors =
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor],
                                  (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = NSCornerRadius;

    return gradientLayer;
}

- (void)changeBackgroundWithLayer:(CALayer*)newLayer
{
    if (_gradientBackground != nil)
        [_gradientBackground removeFromSuperlayer];

    _gradientBackground = newLayer;
    [self.layer insertSublayer:newLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

And I do this to change background layer:

```
[self changeBackgroundWithLayer:[self createLayerWithGradient:startColor endColor:endColor]];
```

And sometimes with this:

```
[self changeBackgroundWithLayer:[self createLayerWithColor:newColor]];
```

The way I do is:
 First solid layer, next gradient layer and finally solid layer.

I have also tried with this code with no result:

```
- (void)changeBackgroundWithLayer:(CALayer*)newLayer
{
    if (_gradientBackground != nil)
        [self.layer replaceSublayer:_gradientBackground with:newLayer];
    else
        [self.layer insertSublayer:newLayer atIndex:0];
    _gradientBackground = newLayer;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

**Any advice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)changeBackgroundWithLayer:(CALayer*)newLayer
{
    [_gradientBackground removeFromSuperlayer], _gradientBackground = nil;
    [self.layer insertSublayer:newLayer atIndex:0];
    _gradientBackground = newLayer;
}
```

This will remove the `_gradientBackground` and set it to `nil` in every case, which is perfectly acceptable in Objective-C. The `newLayer` is added to the layer hierarchy and the `gradientBackground` layer is updated.